# How to normalize each vector of np.gradient elegantly?

Tags: python, numpy

Using the numpy gradient function, one obtains a list of arrays. E.g. in 3 dimensions 3 arrays corresponding to the x,y,z axes. I would like to normalize the gradient for each element.

What I have right now is:

```
gradient = np.gradient(self.image)
gradient_norm = np.sqrt(sum(x**2 for x gradient))
for dim in gradient:
    np.divide(dim, gradient_norm, out=dim)
    np.nan_to_num(dim, copy=False)
```

It seems highly verbose and inelegant for something which I think is not an exotic problem. Also the above does quite a bit of copying which I would like to avoid (as a bonus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the norm with `np.linalg.norm` and simply divide iteratively -

```
norms = np.linalg.norm(gradient,axis=0)
gradient = [np.where(norms==0,0,i/norms) for i in gradient]
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind a `n+1` dim array as output -

```
out = np.where(norms==0,0,gradient/norms)
```

Answer (score 1):

linalg.norm can broadcast with `keepdims=True` key arg

```
g = (np.arange(9) - 4).reshape((3, 3))

g
Out[215]: 
array([[-4, -3, -2],
       [-1,  0,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  4]])

col_norm = g/np.linalg.norm(g, axis=0, keepdims=True)

col_norm
Out[217]: 
array([[-0.87287156, -0.70710678, -0.43643578],
       [-0.21821789,  0.        ,  0.21821789],
       [ 0.43643578,  0.70710678,  0.87287156]])

row_norm = g/np.linalg.norm(g, axis=1, keepdims=True)

row_norm 
Out[219]: 
array([[-0.74278135, -0.55708601, -0.37139068],
       [-0.70710678,  0.        ,  0.70710678],
       [ 0.37139068,  0.55708601,  0.74278135]])
```